Newbie asking: consolidate multiple values (PowerBI)
I’m a newbie in data analytics and still learning. I have a small challenge and would like to ask for a smart way to solve. I’m working on RFM model, and have data look like example below:


phone number is used as identifier
order may have one or multiple phone numbers
I want to group the multiple phone numbers appear in the same order
into one “household”, which we consider a “customer” in our RFM
model.


In the example, we have 2 customers:

customer_1 that has 4 phone numbers: phone_1, phone_2, phone_4,
phone_5
another customer_3 has phone_3

The actual data we have ~4.4M orders. Is there an optimal way to define customer_id that way in PowerBI or any other tool?
Thank you so much!
